# Consider a Stochastic process X which moves between the corners of a regular tetrahedron. Find P(Xn = 1)

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Stochastic process $X$ which moves between the corners of a regular tetrahedron. The process starts at time 0 in node 1. At each time step, the process chooses an one of the connected edges and follows it to a new corner. The edges are selected uniformly, and independently of the past. Let $X_n$ be the number of the corner the process is in after step $n$.

Determine the $P(X_n = 1)$ for all $n$ in the Natural numbers.

- I have done the previous 3 parts to this question, but am completely stumped by this part. There were two hints; you could try $n = 1,2,3$ first and then try to find a formula for general $n$. Or you could turn it into a two-state Markov chain.

Bearing in mind, I have only started introduction to markov processes two weeks ago, it would be greatly aprreciated if somebody could help me out please.

Note: I have found that $P(X_1 = 1)$ = 0, $P(X_2 = 1)$ = 1/3, $P(X_3 = 1)$ = 6/27 - are these correct?

Comment: You are either in State $A$ (the $1$ corner) or State B (one of the other corners). You go from $A$ to $B$ with probability $1$, and from $A$ to $A$ with probability $0$. You go from $B$ to $A$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and from $B$ to $B$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. Use matrices, or write down and solve a recurrence.  But calculating the first few probabilities is always a good idea.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't know how to use matrices or a recurrence to solve this problem. We have literally just started the course and been given this with no examples or guidance from the notes. I have no idea how to go about this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show how to find an answer using not much machinery. Matrices, or recurrences, would make it easier.

At any time, we can be in one of two states, $A$ or $B$, where State $A$ means we are at vertex $1$, and State $B$ means we are at one of the $3$ other vertices.

At time $0$ we are in State $A$.

If at time $n$ we are in State $A$, then with probability $1$ we are in State $B$ at time $n+1$.

If at time $n$ we are in State $B$, then at time $n+1$ we are in State $A$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and remain in State $B$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

Now let us compute:

Time $1$: with probability $0$, we are in State $A$, and with probability $1$ we are in State $B$.

Time $2$: With probability $\frac{1}{3}$ we are in $A$, with probability $1-\frac{1}{3}$ we are in $B$.

From now on, we just calculate the probabilities for $A$. We simplify a bit, but not very much, to preserve structure. It would be a mistake to use a calculator!

Time $3$: With probability $\frac{1}{3}(1-\frac{1}{3})$ we are in $A$. This simplifies to $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}$.

At time $4$, the probability we are in $A$ is $\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}\right)$. This is $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}$.

For time $5$, subtract the answer for $5$ from $1$, and multiply by $\frac{1}{3}$. We get $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27}-\frac{1}{81}$.

The pattern is clear. We can use the expression for the sum of a finite geometric progression to get a closed form for the probability we are in State $A$ at time $n$, that is, for the probability that $X_n=1$.

In general for time $n$, we get 
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots +(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\right).$$
This is a geometric progression with common ratio $-\frac{1}{3}$ and sum
$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3^{n-1}+(-1)^n}{3^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: The fractions $2/27$, $2/81$, and $2/243$ should be $1/27$, $1/81$, and $1/243$ respectively.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Thanks, after the first mistake, cut and paste made sure there would be more.

Comment: Scratch that, I see now you've edited it

Comment: I corrected, it should be clear now. For your question, $1.3\cdot 2/3=1/3\cdot(1-1/3)$.

Comment: Because in my problem we start in state $A$ at t=$0$ not t=$1$, when I have the final form of the probability, I get that it works for n=$-2$ upwards not n=$0$ upwards, so how would I change it to make it correct: I have $P(X_n = 1)$ = (1/3)(1-(-1/3)^n+1)/(1-(-1/3))

Comment: You are right, I did not notice te $0$. will change the indices, and then write down the closed form.